# AS3: Using return keyword in a function that returns void

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, return

Today I've received a small **ActionScript 3** application that I need to have a look at and make some changes to.

I've noticed that the entire application is riddled with the `return` keyword, eg:

```
// Constructor
public function MyClass()
{
    // some logic

    return;
}

public function someFunction():void
{
    // some logic

    return;
}
```

Is there a possible reason for this, or is the developer who worked on this using some weird, self-taught practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` can end a function early if condition is met, the appropriate information has been assigned or passed, etc. while the function has additional code that is not needed, but if all of the `void` functions just have `return` at the end of the function then they are redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I know return ends a function which is good for functions that seek for certain things in an array etc, but these are all just at the end of the function.. Extremely odd and messy in my opinion. Good points for people who come across this page, +1.

Comment: in that case they are not needed and, i agree with you, it's sloppy code.

Comment: My understanding was that the return statement is implied by the compiler if its not explicitly declared. IE - void is returned if that is the function type regardless  of whether its declared or not (tho perhaps I'm mistaken on this point). Similar in this case to the super() call in a subclass. That being said, I disagree that its 'extremely messy'. It may not be required, but it still exists, and the dev may include it simply out of habit, or verbosity, or.... whatever. What would be sloppy is if was included without consistancy. Interesting.

Comment: hummm, i'm not sure.  i feel it's misleading since `return` at the end of a function implies that something is actually being returned.  so if someone was to write it at the end of a void statement than i think, at best, it should be `return null;`, otherwise i think that it's confusing and misused.  on the other hand, we don't write `return null;` when we want to end the function early, though an early `return` is not at the end of the code block.  it's also very uncommon (i've actually never seen it before), which is different than seeing the optional `super();` at the start of a subclass.

Comment: that being said, i personally loath using underscore prefixes to denote private class properties because i think it looks hideous, even though it's common and my refusing to write them that way could be considered confusing.  so let's just say that writing `return;` at the end of a void function is "debatable".  lol.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 really? If anything I loath when people don't  prepend their private properties with an underscore. The only cases where you shouldn't prepend a private property with an underscore are with public, protected and internal properties, in my opinion. However I do admit they can seem a bit ugly at times.

Comment: Interesting discussion - honestly, I think that, as long as the author is consistent, and seems to draw on some type of rationale, "proper" convention can vary pretty widely. As long as these conventions match the habits of the dev team (if you are working with one), then "anything goes" (within reason). The one I struggle with is the opening brace of a function block - to return or not return! Also - the choice between camel casing or underscore separation of function names.